# c# geocoordinate watcher not giving back correct coords

Tags: c#, geolocation

I wrote a c# code to get my coarse position.

The program will run on a laptop, which doesn't have GPS sensors.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    {
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

    public void GetLocationDataEvent()
    {
        watcher = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.PositionChanged += watcher_PositionChanged;
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {

        String lat = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString();
        String lon = e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(lat + "+" + lon);
        // Stop receiving updates after the first one.
        watcher.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Well, it works. But it gives me a coord that is nearly 30km away from my position. Are there any other approach to make it more accurate? I can afford about 1 or 2 kms of inaccuracy, but this is just too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect without GPS sensors?

GPS is accurate to about 5m on average.

If there are no GPS sensors your OS might:

- map your IP address (which is just a rough estimate)
- map your WLAN ID (better, but still just an estimate)
- if you have a GSM module, it may use the nearest GSM sender (accurate to 30 km)

Morale: If you need the exact position you need a GPS module.

Comment: Well, it appears that this link(http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation) gives me an accurate location, when using with Chrome. Using C# wasn't the correct approach.

Comment: In my Firefox (no GPS) this is 3 km off (much better than expected) (Chrom returns the same results)

Comment: It seems that Chrome and Firefox are using the w3c geolocation standard. That's why they are getting very accurate location. But, IE doesn't seem accurate at all. Running the source on IE returns the same location of the result above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, but after starting the GeoCoordinateWatcher the first positions are often inaccurate.

If another application has used your position recently, the GeoCoordinateWather quickly can deliver a accurate position, but if not it first has to start other location services on your computer, and this can take some time.

You could add a check for accuracy:

```
private void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    if (e.Position.Location.HorizontalAccuracy > 500)
    {
        return;
    }

    String lat = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString();
    String lon = e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(lat + "+" + lon);
    // Stop receiving updates after the first one.
    watcher.Stop();
}
```

This will keep waiting until the accuracy is at least 500 meters.